# PowerApps - onChange not triggering after Publishing, triggering in editor App Preview (F5)

Tags: sharepoint, onchange, sharepoint-online, preview, powerapps

This is a bit of a weird one:
Attempting to publish a PowerApp to my site however some of the onChange events are not firing after being published. The Preview in the app is working fine, however the version published to the site does not.

I have tried restarting PowerApps, the browser, my computer, republishing after each with no luck. Anyone run into this issue before and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - After hours of messing with this I got it to work but the solution doesn't resolve the bug, just gets my desired result.

What I was doing:

Specifically what is happening I am using an onchange event from a dropdown to assist in naming the title of the same list item.

```html
OnChange: UpdateContext({varNewName: "example text"})
```

However, the title box simply wouldn't update after being published. In the preview mode in the developer environment it was running fine.

I decided to duplicate the box for laughs, tested it, both updated in preview mode just fine.

Published it and the original box was now working, the second box however was now doing nothing. If anyone knows why this is happening I would love to know, it is driving me nuts.

**TLDR:** If you are having this issue duplicate the recieving end of your trigger and it might resolve. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Don't forget to hit "Publish"! Saving alone does not instantiate changes, only publishing does!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with rating control.
After a long day, I changed default value of binding source from Blank() to Zero. And it works fine!